# Pass %%local variables from dotenv run in jupyter to Azure HDInsight pyspark cluster

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

## Intro

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-jupyter-notebook-install-locally) details how to install jupyter locally and work against an Azure HDInsight cluster. This works well getting things setup.

However:

1. Not all python packages that we have available locally are available on the cluster.
2. Some local processing may want to be done before 'submitting' a cell to the cluster.

I'm aware that python packages that are not installed can be installed via [script actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-python-package-installation) and [`%%configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-jupyter-notebook-use-external-packages), however given our use of `dotenv` locally these don't seem to be viable solutions.

## Problem

1. Source control with git
2. Git repos are local on dev machines We store
   configuration/sensitive environment variables in `.env` files
   locally (they are not checked into git)
3. `dotenv` package is used to
   read sensitive variables and set locally for execution
4. blob storage
   account names and keys are example of these variables
5. **how to pass these locally set variables to a pyspark cell?**

---

## Local cell example

[image]

## Followed by pyspark cell

[image]

Comment: found a solution for this? :)